# ExtJs - how correctly implement the code as an event

Tags: extjs

I have code:

```
    ...
function Edit(id) { ... }
...

view : new Ext.grid.GroupingView({
    groupTextTpl   : '... <a href="#" onClick="Edit({[values.rs[0].data["id"]]})">link</a>...'
    ...
```

Everything works, but it would be something on the similarity:

```
    ...
Ext.get('edit').on('click', function() {
    alert(this.getValue());
});
...

view : new Ext.grid.GroupingView({
    groupTextTpl   : '... <a href="#" id="edit" value="{[values.rs[0].data["id"]]}">link</a>...'
    ...
```

But for some reason does not work, error - Ext.get ("edit") is null.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you execute `Ext.get('edit')` before creating the `GroupView`, the '<a id="edit" ...>' has not been injected to the DOM yet, so you can't get it with `Ext.get('edit')`. Try running `Ext.get('edit')` later.

Comment: thank you), everything was easier than I thought)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ext.get('edit')` gets called before it is created, hence the error. Put the `Ext.get()` below the `GroupingView()`